# Issue in downloading byte array as file in Internet Explorer( 9 and below) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, internet-explorer, arrays

I have a byte array that needs to be downloaded as a file on user's machine. **I was able to achieve this in chrome but not in IE(9 and below).**

**Code#1** - *Works in Chrome but gives access denied error in IE.*

```
var a = window.document.createElement('a');
a.href = "data:" +strMimeType+ "," +escape(byteArray);
a.download = "Test";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

**Code#2** - *Works in Chrome but nothing happens in IE.*

```
a.href = "data:" +strMimeType+ "," +escape(byteArray);
var a = window.document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute("download", n);
document.body.appendChild(a);
var e= document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
e.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(e);
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

**Code#3** - *Works in Chrome but gives access denied error in IE.*

```
var content="data:" +strMimeType+ "," +escape(byteArray);
window.open("content","_blank","");
```

Comment: download attribute is not supported in IE before Edge 13 nor in Safari. `escape` is deprecated and should be replaced by `encodeURIComponent()` not sure where your problem comes from though. Where does the byte array comes from? Is IE<9 even able to see it as a bytearray?

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks. So there is no way to download byte array as file in IE ?

Comment: Well I'm not an expert in IE but I know that typedArrays were only introduced in IE 10. If you do serve your byteArray in such a typedArray, there are chances that it is not recognized. Now am not sure either how the dataURI were supported in those *browsers*. Wait for an answer from someone with more knowledge.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the info.

Comment: I am ok to become that "someone with more knowledge" (by learning), bt I would need that you include an example of the byteArray you have or at least, more info on how you get it.

Comment: @Kaiido I am calling a webservice which returns the mime type of a document(pdf,word and etc) and its content as byte array.

Comment: Are you this is a byteArray and not a binaryString that you got?